# How to get Session Expire DateTime when using StateServer in C#

Tags: c#

How to get Session Expire DateTime when using StateServer mode?

InProc mode has the function Session_End which can't get executed when using StateServer mode.

Comment: Store the value in the session, or store when the session was created and add the default expiry?

Comment: @Adriani6 I want to store the date time when session expired.

Comment: You need to calculate it.